# How to show JAX-RS elements in Eclipse Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse, web-services, ide, jax-rs, eclipse-luna

I am sure that I'm just missing something silly, and I've done this before, however, after upgrading to Eclipse Luna, I can no longer see my JAX-RS Web Services in the Project Explorer.  I vaguely remembered that there was a check box in the Project properties that I could use to turn on this feature.  I have scoured the Project properties, but I can't find it.  Curiously, I know how to turn off the JAX-WS services - but that doesn't help me. Any help?

EDIT:  What I was really asking here was:  What happened to the JAX-RS Validator in the Project properties in Luna?  Well, I found the answer - see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer.  I uninstalled and then reinstalled the JBoss Tools from Luna.  Apparently, the OOTB Luna installation (that ostensibly comes with JBoss Tools already installed) has some issues.  Namely, the JAX-RS Validator project configuration does not show up in the Project Properties dialog.

I just uninstalled JBoss Tools and then reinstalled from the Eclipse Marketplace.  Things are working much better now.